# How to get sorted a TreeMap from list using streams

Tags: java, collections, java-8, java-stream

I have a class say Level (its just a dummy class for understanding).
I want a sorted `TreeMap<Level,Set<String>>` based on levelId.
Please find below code

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

    public class Level {
        int levelId;

        public Level(int levelId) {
            this.levelId = levelId;
        }

        public static Level getLevel(String name){
            return new Level(name.length());
        }

        public static void main(String[]args){
            Set<String> names=new HashSet<>();
            names.add("Mahesh");
            names.add("Ram");
            names.add("Rita");

            Map<Level, Set<String>> map = names.stream().collect(
                    Collectors.groupingBy(name->Level.getLevel(name),
                    Collectors.mapping(name->name,Collectors.toSet())));

        }
    }
```

I have also tried with `Collectors.collectingAndThen()`.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Supplier-java.util.stream.Collector-

Comment: Use a for loop rather than streams

Comment: `Collectors.groupingBy(Level::getLevel, TreeMap::new, Collectors.toSet())`

Comment: yes can use loop but it will be better if can achieve this using streams.

Comment: @4castle i need sorted TreeMap on levelId

Comment: Try Collectors.groupingBy(Level::getLevel, TreeMap::new, Collectors.mapping(l -> l, Collectors.toSet()))

Comment: @Nidhi257 For the `TreeMap` to sort based on `levelId`, you will need to make `Level` implement the `Comparable<Level>` interface.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you don’t want to let `Level` implement `Comparable`, you need a `Comparator`. Then, you have to pass a lambda expression creating a `TreeMap` using this separator as map factory to the `groupingBy` collector:

```
public class Level {
    int levelId;

    public Level(int levelId) {
        this.levelId = levelId;
    }

    public static Level getLevel(String name){
        return new Level(name.length());
    }

    public int getLevelId() {
        return levelId;
    }

    public static void main(String[]args){
        Set<String> names=new HashSet<>();
        names.add("Mahesh");
        names.add("Ram");
        names.add("Rita");

        Comparator<Level> c = Comparator.comparingInt(Level::getLevelId);
        Map<Level, Set<String>> map = names.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                         Level::getLevel, () -> new TreeMap<>(c), Collectors.toSet()));
    }
}
```

Comment: Can we inverse treeMap order?

Comment: Sure. Just append [`.reversed()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Comparator.html#reversed()) to `Comparator.comparingInt(Level::getLevelId)`

Answer (score 6):

Your modified working code would look like this, please see @4castle comments:

```
public class Level implements Comparable<Level> {
    int levelId;

    public Level(int levelId) {
        this.levelId = levelId;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Level o) {
        return Integer.compare(levelId, o.levelId);
    }

    public static Level getLevel(String name){
        return new Level(name.length());
    }

    public static void main(String[]args){
        Set<String> names=new HashSet<>();
        names.add("Mahesh");
        names.add("Ram");
        names.add("Rita");

        Map<Level, Set<String>> map = names.stream().collect(
                Collectors.groupingBy(Level::getLevel, TreeMap::new,
                        Collectors.toSet()));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, using streams improves readability only in the simplest cases. If you have specific requirements, such as you need a specific `Map` implementation, or you need to use a custom `Comparator`, I would strongly encourage using a for loop instead. Yes, you could search the `Collectors` class for an appropriate method, but I believe the resulting code is harder to follow and less flexible if you need to make another small change later.

In Java 8, there were many improvements to the `Map` interface which mean doing this kind of thing in a loop is now much less painful than had previously been the case.

```
Map<Level, Set<String>> result = new TreeMap<>(Comparator.comparingInt(level -> level.levelId));
for (String name : names)
    result.computeIfAbsent(getLevel(name), k -> new HashSet<>()).add(name);
```

In this case, I am not sure why you want a map with `Level` keys anyway. Since you want to group by id, wouldn't it make more sense for the keys to be `Integer`s?

```
Map<Integer, Set<String>> result = new TreeMap<>();
for (String name : names)
    result.computeIfAbsent(getLevel(name).levelId, k -> new HashSet<>()).add(name);
```

Comment: I suppose, the `Level getLevel(String name)` method of the question is just a placeholder for the actual operation. There are [similar real life classes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/?java/util/logging/Level.html). By the way, I don’t think that a [stream based solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46704101/2711488) is less readable than the loop alternative. There are cases where a loop is much better, but I wouldn’t say that the threshold has been crossed here.